# Why is $f(x)=x$ continuous but not continuous in graph?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Define: $f(x)=x$ with domain: $D=\{x=\frac{1}n\cup x=0~|~n\in\mathbb{Z}\cap n\neq0 \}$

We study the continuity at $x=0$

$$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists \delta=\epsilon, \forall x, |x-0|<\delta \cap x\in D,\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(0)|=|x-0|<\delta=\epsilon$$

So function $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$. But if we look at the graph, apparently, the function is defined as discrete points. So continuous function in definition is not necessarily continuous in graph, right?

Comment: The domain is discrete, so the function is not a straight line.

Comment: What is your definition of "continuous in graph"? Of course the graph of a function will have gaps if you consider a domain consisting (mostly) of isolated points.

Comment: Because when $n$ increases, the value of function $\frac 1 n$ get closer and closer to $0$. This is enough to satisfy the rigorous def oc *continuity* that is aimed at formalizing the intuitive notion of "the graph of a continuous function can be drawn without removing the pencil from paper".

Comment: yes, that's what I mean, there are gaps in graph, so it is not continuous graphically @jakobdt

Comment: With this domain, the function is continuous at $x=\frac1n$ for any positive integer $n$, and in a sense the graph *looks* even more continuous at $x=0$.  There are no gaps in the image of $f$ that do not correspond to gaps in the domain of $f$

Comment: One more reason to ban the "can be drawn without lifting the pencil" slogan.

Comment: I thought it is against the intuition, because we have to lift the pen from the paper to make those discrete dots. @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: You are correct: this example shows that continuity and « continuity in graph » (this could be defined more formally as « connectedness - in some way - of the graph » are not equivalent (they might be in some cases…). So forget everything about « lifting the pen blahblahblah » and just remember the $\epsilon$, $\delta$ definition.

Comment: On this domain it looks to me as if it continuous at $x= \frac1n$.  For any $\varepsilon >0$, take $\delta=\frac{1}{3n^2}$; the only value of $y \in D$ with $\frac1n-\frac1{3n^2} < y < \frac1n+\frac1{3n^2}$ is $y= \frac1n$, and clearly for that $y$ you have $|y-\frac1n|=0\lt \varepsilon$

Comment: ah, right, function is continuous at all isolated points @Henry